# Adding column vlookup and color row

Tags: vba, excel

I have work book which has 2 sheets 
Sheet1(No,Host,date,String,ID,TKT)
Data ( ID & Name )

I want to create a single Macro which can add column with name and vlookup iD in data sheet and return name and change the color using id column

**What i have**

I have 2 separate Macros 
1- Macro to change the color using id column

Worksheet code

```
Sub ChangeColor()
lRow = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set MR = Range("E2:E" & lRow)
For Each cell In MR
Select Case cell.Value
Case "x12340"
cell_colour = 2
Case "x12341"
cell_colour = 6
cell.EntireRow.Font.ColorIndex = 4
Case "x12342"
cell_colour=6 
cell.EntireRow.Font.ColorIndex = 2
Case "x12343"
cell_colour=7 
cell.EntireRow.Font.ColorIndex = 2
Case "x12344"
cell_colour=8 
cell.EntireRow.Font.ColorIndex = 2
Case "x12345"
cell_colour=9 
cell.EntireRow.Font.ColorIndex = 2
Case Else
cell_colour = 1
cell.EntireRow.Font.ColorIndex = 4
End Select
cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = cell_colour
Next
End Sub
```

2- Macro to add column in Sheet1 with header Name
Sheet 1

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rngUsernameHeader As Range
Dim rngHeaders As Range

Set rngHeaders = Range("1:1") 'Looks in entire first row.
Set rngUsernameHeader = rngHeaders.Find(what:="ID", After:=Cells(1, 1))

rngUsernameHeader.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
rngUsernameHeader.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Name"

End Sub
```

**What iam looking for**

Single Macro which can do

1 & 2 and also vlookup iD from sheet1 in data sheet(Id & name) and return name on newly added column(Name) in sheet1

```
=VLOOKUP(E2,Data!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

Can you pls help on this

Thanks
HR

Comment: Are you asking how to add a Vlookup over a range, in VBA?    Also that first macro can be replaced entirely with simple Conditional Formatting, unless I'm missing something?  Also, why do you have `Case Else` in the middle of the `Select Case` code?

Comment: What do you mean by `"add column with name and vlookup iD "`? Maybe if you included a screenshot with what you have, and what you want as output?

Comment: asking how to add a Vlookup over a range, in VBA? - Yes Sir 
The reason why i haven't used conditional formatting is because i have too many id's here i just added few of them. 
Case else - Type :-) @BruceWayne

Comment: I have written code for Adding column (2) and changing color (1)and now iam looking how to vlookup by vba (3) and merge all 3 into 1 code @PGCodeRider

Comment: @HarshaReddy why not just copy in your click command macro into your your change color macro? again screenshots or clearer vision would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very possibly not understanding your question, but if you just want to add in a VLookup function in the `rngUsernameHeader.Offset(0, 1)` column and run the change-color macro, you could change your `Sub` to look as follows:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rngUsernameHeader As Range
Dim rngHeaders As Range

    Set rngHeaders = Range("1:1") 'Looks in entire first row.
    Set rngUsernameHeader = rngHeaders.Find(what:="ID", After:=Cells(1, 1))

    rngUsernameHeader.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
    rngUsernameHeader.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Name"

    ' Add in the VLookup:
    rngUsernameHeader.Offset(1, 1).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(E2,Data!A:B,2,FALSE)"

    ' Run the ChangeColor Macro:
    ChangeColor

End Sub
```

Hope that helps move you in the correct direction.

Comment: ' Add in the VLookup:
    rngUsernameHeader.Offset(1, 1).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(E2,Data!A:B,2,FALSE)"

Can you pls let me know how to loop abv vlookup @John Bustos

Comment: I'd need more information... Can you explain more of the `E2` and what that will look like in the VLookup as you go down? So, would row 3 be `E3`, or would it still stay `E2` etc? Also, do you know how many rows you'd need it for / how could you know how many rows to go down for?